# Separating out a DB field in SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to use a SQL statement to separate out fields in a DB?

For instance, using `u.address` in a SQL statement returns `{"city": "Fullerton", "first": "369 Acacia Ave", "state": "California", "second": "", "country": "United States", "zipcode": "92831"}`

I want each of those address fields in a separate column in Excel. I apologize if this is easy. I'm not well versed in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it after you get what was returned from the database.

x={"city": "Fullerton", "first": "369 Acacia Ave", "state": "California", "second": "", "country": "United States", "zipcode": "92831"}

print(x["city"])

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `address` column is formatted as a JSON document. MySQL 5.7 and later versions support JSON functions, so you can do the following query:

```
SELECT
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.address, '$.city')) AS `city`,
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.address, '$.first')) AS `first`,
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.address, '$.state')) AS `state`,
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.address, '$.second')) AS `second`,
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.address, '$.country')) AS `country`,
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.address, '$.zipcode')) AS `zipcode`
FROM ...
```

There's also a shorthand syntax:

```
SELECT
  u.address->>'$.city' AS `city`,
  ...and similar for each field...
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract

To be honest, in almost every case where I see JSON used in a MySQL database, it would have been better to use normal columns.

Here's a demo:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/24U6g9FeHqZSfWtgKFKNkG/0

Comment: I used the shorthand and it returned NULL values. Here is what I used:

``` u.address->>'$.city' AS city,
          u.address->>'$.first' AS first,
          u.address->>'$.state' AS state,
          u.address->>'$.second' AS second,
          u.address->>'$.country' AS country,
          u.address->>'$.zipcode' AS zipcode,```

Comment: I added a link to a db-fiddle demo using MySQL 5.7, using your sample data.

Comment: When I run it with the ` it returns an error, but when I run it without the ` it just returns NULL values. So mine looks like:  ``` u.address->>'$.city' AS city,
  u.address->>'$.first' AS first,
  u.address->>'$.state' AS state,
  u.address->>'$.second' AS second,
  u.address->>'$.country' AS country,
  u.address->>'$.zipcode' AS zipcode,```

Comment: Is the JSON data as you showed in your question above? Or did you show just a part of it?

Comment: Yes, although it appears as if the first 20 records in the DB don't have the city. They look like: `{"first": "A", "state": "V", "second": "", "country": "United States", "zipcode": "D"}`

Would that be the issue?

Comment: What does the manual page I linked to say about the return value of JSON_EXTRACT() if the field is not present in a document?